# how to fix header in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to fix the header in Magneto2. Can any one tell me how it work.

```
require([ "jquery" ], function($){

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top && !($('#header').hasClass('sticky'))){
    $('#header-2').addClass('sticky');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
    $('#header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
});
```

and then add some css to this sticky class like this

## header.sticky {

```
background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-bottom: 4px solid #325052;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["jquery"], function($){
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.page-header'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 400) sticky.addClass('mini-header');
  else sticky.removeClass('mini-header');
});
</script>
```

**.css**

```
.page-header.mini-header{possition:fixed}
```

Comment: which file i use this code

Comment: try any of your .phtml file if it's work then change it as proper js and css file